# How to remove black background in app icon in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, appicon

I want to remove black background from my app icon . What is the best possible way to that to add full transparency in background.

Screenshot of the icon - [AppIcon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYzIn.jpg)

Comment: Use a png image instead of jpg

Comment: Some launchers apply the default background to app icons. Does it happen to every icons in your device?

Comment: put your image in this website [link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher) 

 and make the shape ( none )   otherwise if not work some of android version put it by force

Comment: i am using png only @nupadhyaya

Comment: My launcher apply white background but I have made transparency 0 % in Image Assest so it is showing Black colour . @HaiHack

Comment: where have you placed your icon in? asset folder or drawable folder?